# Erlang Lists: Flatten a nested list

Tags: list, erlang, flatten

Given erlang list is `L = [[ [], [1,3], [4,5] ]].`
Output expected is `[[1,3], [4,5]]`

I tried with `lists:flatten/1` but it returns the flattened list as `[1,3,4,5]`.

Comment: Your description is not complete. You should write what is your exact goal: input type (how many nested level in your list, type of members...), operation to perform and output type. If you do this properly, 80% of the job is done.

Answer (score 0):

This question is ambiguous, as it does not really tell us how flattening needs to be done. Just from your input/output example, it appears you only want to flatten one level and ignore the empty lists. This can be achieved via:

```
1> lists:filter(fun (X) -> X /= [] end, lists:append([[ [], [1,3], [4,5] ]])).
[[1,3],[4,5]]
```

But one can imagine other flattenings as well that fit these criteria. Hope this gets you started!

Answer (score 0):

no, flatten function returns a list with elements that are not lists, it eliminates all lists inside the list entered.
if you did an efficient algorithm, you don't need to flatten any list so the best way to create lists is to add elements at the head of list and try to never use the `++` and the `--` operators.